# scipy.optimize.curve_fitのような、任意のグラフで回帰できるアルゴリズムをjavascriptで作成したい(それに準するライブラリをお教えしてほしい。 or シグモイド関数にのみ特化した回帰のためのアルゴリズムを教えてほしい。) )

Tags: python, javascript, 深層学習, scipy

scipy.optimize.curve_fitのような、任意のグラフで回帰できるアルゴリズムをjavascriptで作成したいです。自分が見つけたライブラリが以下のURLになります。

https://www.npmjs.com/package/regression

ですがこれは、単純な線形回帰や対数回帰など、特定のグラフの回帰しかできません。
私が回帰させたい基準となるグラフ(コード部分はpythonで書いたものです)は

シグモイド関数
http://ailaby.com/sigmoid_coef/

```
def pf(x, alpha, beta):
    return 1 /( 1 + np.exp( -alpha - beta * x ))
```

になります。
ですのでやりたいこととしては、
1、scipy.optimize.curve_fitのような、任意のグラフで回帰できるアルゴリズムをお教えしてほしい。
2、1が難しい場合、シグモイド関数にのみ特化した回帰のためのアルゴリズムを教えてほしい。

以上です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.curve_fit` が利用しているアルゴリズムはドキュメントに書かれています: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

> method{‘lm’, ‘trf’, ‘dogbox’}

それぞれ以下の手法です。

> - ‘trf’ : Trust Region Reflective algorithm, particularly suitable for large sparse problems with bounds. Generally robust method.
> - ‘dogbox’ : dogleg algorithm with rectangular trust regions, typical use case is small problems with bounds. Not recommended for problems with rank-deficient Jacobian.
> - ‘lm’ : Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm as implemented in MINPACK. Doesn’t handle bounds and sparse Jacobians. Usually the most efficient method for small unconstrained problems.